# ERROR in The target entry-point "ngx-restangular" has missing dependencies: core-js/features/object

Tags: ionic-framework, core-js, ngx-restangular

When i start 'ionic serve' i have this issue

[ng] ERROR in The target entry-point "ngx-restangular" has missing dependencies:
[ng]  - core-js/features/object

And the app don't show in browser.

My Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~9.0.7",
"@angular/core": "~9.0.7",
"@angular/forms": "~9.0.7",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.7",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.7",
"@angular/router": "~9.0.7",
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.7",
"@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.27.0",
"@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.35.0",
"@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^5.27.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
"cordova-android": "~7.0.0",
"cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
"cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.4.1",
"ngx-permissions": "^8.1.1",
"ngx-restangular": "^5.0.0",
"rxjs": "~6.5.4",
"tslib": "^1.10.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
```

},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.5",
"@angular/cli": "9.1.15",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.0.7",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.7",
"@angular/language-service": "~9.0.7",
"@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
"jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~5.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"protractor": "~5.4.3",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~3.7.3"
},

Help please

Comment: Did you figure out the solution? I am getting similar error.

Comment: Hello,
I ran this command and my problem was solved
npm i --legacy-peer-deps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran

```
npm i core-js --legacy-peer-deps
```

and my problem was solved